# How to invoke second page only when click on text item in list

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have report which has two page says page1 and page2. Page1 has list object. When I run the report page1 should display with list column values. when I click any of test item from list column1 then second page should appear. Please can you guide me how to achieve this in cognos report studio.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the page to advance and not a drill-through. You can do this with JavaScript.

This method turns every value into a link that will invoke the next page when clicked:

1. Unlock the report
2. Put an HTML Item to the left of your data item that you want to be clicked.
3. For the HTML Item expression, supply the following code: `<a href="#" onclick="advancePage()">`
4. Add another HTML Item to the right of your data item with the following expression: `</a>`
5. Add a third HTML Item to the bottom of your report
6. Supply the following expression for the HTML Item:

**JS Code:**

```
function advancePage() {
    var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
    report.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.NEXT);
}
```

There are other variations. For instance, you could use a button instead of a text link. For all the variations, the essential technique is the same.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I achieved this using render variable. Below links helped me : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSOpi1Obsho